# Changing DriveApp.Permission of a file/folder

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, google-drive-api

I am spending hours (literally) trying to find a way to change the `DriveApp.Permission` of my script (for web App).

Actually, its value is VIEW, not allowing me to create folders, files or edit them (read only).

The script is configured to run as "me", accessible for anyone.

I have checked the owner of the folder ( `FOLDER.getOwner().getEmail();` )  and owner of the user/session ( `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` ).

Not surprisingly, they've returned the same value. I have read [THIS](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions), but without success in retrieving any useful information.

I think, the problem is around the `DriverApp.Permission` value.

I was brief as a possible, I think. Could someone help me?

To put it clear: the script, the driver, etc., all of them belongs to me ( \o/ ).

Example:

`DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFoldersByName( "ExistingFolder" ).next().createFile(  "No_authorized_it_will_not_be_created_and_will_trigger_a_exepction" , "Some TEXT" );`

**Google GET response (translated/approximated)**

> Exception: You don't have permission to call DriveApp.Folder.createFile. You need to have permissions :https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive (line 135, file "InternalDriver")

Comment: Did you authorize the script before you deployed it? Try manually adding the scope to your manifest. Your users will only be able to access what you can access.

Comment: yes. I think, If I haven't done this, the DriveApp.Permission value wouldn't be VIEW.

Comment: Did you try adding the scope manually and then reauthorize?

Comment: How I do that? >.< 
Certainly, I haven't.

Comment: Here's what the scopes look like in the manifest: `"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects.readonly"],`  Just go into the manifest and see if it's not already there then just add it manually.  If the  scopes are not the last item on the list then there needs to be comma at the end.  The documentation has some info on editing the manifest https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Is any that working for you?

Comment: 1.Have you deployed a *new version* of your app? 2. Are you pinging `/exec` url and not the `/dev` url? 3. Run a function in your editor to trigger auth flow.

Comment: @Copper. That was the point! Now, I know have learn the basic about manifest and authorizations. I think I am a step to resolve the problem. I've changed the manifest, have added the oauthScopes property and its urls list. Now... I have no idea how to concede permission to my script ( O.O ). I have deleted the older permission, believing that a new one would automatically requested, but not!

Comment: Now I get a new message: You need authorization to execute this action (free translation).


@TheMaster - good questions. I have stumbled in this issue once. I am using dev version.

Comment: $TheMaster... thinking  about what you said... I've decided to deploy a new version after @Copper recommendations. I've got a new folder and a new file in my driver (after accept the new permissions request)!

Thank you a lot! NO WORDS... T.T

Comment: Daniel would you consider posting an answer explaining how your issue got solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With support of @Copper and suggestion of @TheMaster, my solution:

Add this JSON object to the manifest

```
"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
```

Create a new version of the project, and try it again.

I have removed the actual permission related to project before deploy a new version.

I'm not sure whether "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents" path is necessary for simple creation or edition of folders/files. The other path string is certainly needed.